# Make an up down counter using structural design

Tags: vhdl, counter

I've tried to made a 4 bit up down counter using structural design .
My code is the following :

```
entity counter4bit is
    Port ( clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           load : in  STD_LOGIC;
           enable : in  STD_LOGIC;
           counterOut : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           updown : in  STD_LOGIC);
end counter4bit;

architecture Behavioral of counter4bit is

component D_FlipFlop
    Port ( d : in  STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
           load : in  STD_LOGIC;
           enable : in  STD_LOGIC;
           updown : in  STD_LOGIC;
           q : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component MUX 
    Port ( i0 : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           i1 : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           i2 : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           i3 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           inload : in  STD_LOGIC;
           bitout : out  STD_LOGIC;
           load : in  STD_LOGIC;
           updown : in  STD_LOGIC;
           en : in  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

signal w: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal cnt : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin

FF0 : D_FlipFlop
    port map( d => w(0),
                 reset => reset,
                 clock =>clock,
                 load => load,
                 enable => enable,
                 updown => updown,
                 q => cnt(0) );

FF1 : D_FlipFlop
    port map( d => w(1),
                 reset => reset,
                 Clock => clock,
                 load => load,
                 enable => enable,
                 updown => updown,
                 q => cnt(1));

FF2 : D_FlipFlop
    port map( d => w(2),
                 reset => reset,
                 clock => clock,
                 load => load,
                 enable => enable,
                 updown => updown,
                 q => cnt(2));

FF3 : D_FlipFlop
    port map( d => w(3),
                 reset => reset,
                 clock => clock,
                 load => load,
                 enable => enable,
                 updown => updown,
                 q => cnt(3));

MUX0 : MUX
    port map( i0 => '1',
                 i1 => '1',
                 i2 => '1',
                 i3 => cnt(0),
                 inload => '1',
                 bitout =>w(0) ,
                 load => load,
                 updown => updown,
                 en => enable);

MUX1 : MUX
    port map( i0 => cnt(0),
                 i1 =>'1',
                 i2 => '1',
                 i3 => cnt(1),
                 inload => '1',
                 bitout =>w(1) ,
                 load => load,
                 updown => updown,
                 en => enable); 

MUX2 : MUX
    port map( i0 => cnt(0),
                 i1 => cnt(1),
                 i2 =>  '1',
                 i3 => cnt(2),
                 inload => '0',
                 bitout =>w(2) ,
                 load => load,
                 updown => updown,
                 en => enable);

MUX3 : MUX
    port map( i0 => cnt(0),
                 i1 => cnt(1),
                 i2 =>cnt(2),
                 i3 => cnt(3),
                 inload => '0',
                 bitout =>w(3) ,
                 load => load,
                 updown => updown,
                 en => enable);

counterOut <= cnt ;

end Behavioral;
```

When I simulate it it starts from 0 as it should cause of the reset , then counts to 1 and then again 0 . I can't see why it goes back to 0 after 1.

Here is my code for mux :

```
entity MUX is
    Port ( i0 : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           i1 : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           i2 : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           i3 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           inload : in  STD_LOGIC;
           bitout : out  STD_LOGIC;
           load : in  STD_LOGIC;
           updown : in  STD_LOGIC;
           en : in  STD_LOGIC);
end MUX;

architecture Behavioral of MUX is
signal  sel : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal y, z, x: std_logic;
begin

y <= (updown and i0 and i1 and i2 and en);
z <= (not updown) and i0 and i1 and i2 and en;

sel(0) <= not load;
sel(1) <= y or z ;

process(sel, x)
    begin 
        if sel = "00" then x<= i3;
        elsif sel = "01" then x <= (not i3);
        else    x <= inload;
        end if;
    end process;
    bitout <= x ;
end Behavioral;
```

And the code for Flip Flop :

```
entity D_FlipFlop is
    Port ( d : in  STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
           load : in  STD_LOGIC;
           enable : in  STD_LOGIC;
           updown : in  STD_LOGIC;
           q : out  STD_LOGIC);
end D_FlipFlop;

architecture Behavioral of D_FlipFlop is

begin

process(clock, reset)
begin
    if (reset = '0') then
        q <= '0';
    elsif (rising_edge(clock)) then
        q <= d;
    end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

I have to note that load and enable are synchronous while reset is asynchronous, i will also attach one picture of my simulation .[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I simulate it it starts from 0 as it should cause of the reset , then counts to 1 and then again 0 . I can't see why it goes back to 0 after 1.

I modified yesterday's testbench to duplicate your waveform:

[image: counter4bit_tb_duplicate.png]

I had to modify reset with a '0' to '1' and '1' to '0' set of delta cycles to get counterout to show up as all '0's.

The first thing to notice is that you have the reset polarity wrong.

Fixing that gives:

[image: counter4bit_tb_wrong_sensitivity.png]

And we can see the count didn't increment properly and still stalls.

Without going into the polarity of load the stalled values are caused by the sensitivity list for the process in MUX:

```
process(sel, x)
    begin 
        if sel = "00" then x<= i3;
        elsif sel = "01" then x <= (not i3);
        else    x <= inload;
        end if;
    end process;
    bitout <= x ;
end Behavioral;
```

which should have a sensitivity list of:

```
 process (sel, i3, inload) -- was (sel, x) -- incorrect sensitivity list
```

And that produces:

[image: counter4bit_tb_sensitivity_fixed.png]

which still has a lack of increments showing, but does get a change.

Changing the load value to '0' in the testbench gives us the missing transactions on counterout, but the values are still wrong:

[image: counter4bit_tb_load_low.png]

which tells us either your select equations are wrong or your multiplexer inputs are wrong or some combination of both.

In any event MUX appears to be where you should concentrate.

So by putting in your selects changes in MUX you tell us in comments gives you a correct upcount:

```
-- sel(0) <= not load;
-- sel(1) <= y or z ;
sel(1) <= (not load);  -- per comments
sel(0) <= y or z;
```

We get:

[image: counter4bit_tb_selects_changed.png]

which shows the upcount correct but not the down count. Note the polarity of load has been changed in the selects, and is matched in the waveform above.

Now we know that we're either supposed to increment or decrement cnt based on updown, and

```
y <= updown and i0 and i1 and i2 and en;
```

works for counting up, which leaves

```
z <= not updown and i0 and i1 and i2 and en;
```

Which unfortunately uses the same value on i0, i1 and i2 to toggle bitout (the input to the respective D_FlipFlop for a particular cnt element).

We're fairly sure z wants to be:

```
z <= not updown and not i0 and not i1 and not i2 and en;
```

for decrementing (not updown).

When we make that change count doesn't work. What we need the unused inputs to the MUX's to be the right value for updown, '1' for up (as now)) or '0' for down.

And we can do that with updown in counter4bit:

```
MUX0 : MUX
    port map( i0 => updown, -- '1'
                 i1 => updown, -- '1',
                 i2 => updown, -- '1',
                 i3 => cnt(0),
                 inload => '1',
                 bitout =>w(0) ,
                 load => load,
                 updown => updown,
                 en => enable);

MUX1 : MUX
    port map( i0 => cnt(0),
                 i1 => updown,  -- '1',
                 i2 => updown, -- '1',
                 i3 => cnt(1),
                 inload => '1',
                 bitout =>w(1) ,
                 load => load,
                 updown => updown,
                 en => enable); 

MUX2 : MUX
    port map( i0 => cnt(0),
                 i1 => cnt(1),
                 i2 => updown, -- '1',
                 i3 => cnt(2),
                 inload => '0',
                 bitout =>w(2) ,
                 load => load,
                 updown => updown,
                 en => enable);
```

And this gives us:

[image: counter4bit_tb_working.png]

Notice this waveform doesn't yet test load or enable (false), but it counts up, then back down successfully.

There are also some unused ports on the D_FlipFlop (load, enable, updown).

Comment: I want my counter to be counting from 0000 to 1111 and down to 0 again. You mean my code for mux is wrong ?

Comment: I found what was wrong it was the selects . My problem is now that it is counting only up . when it reaches 1111 it goes to 0000 but i want 1110. Do you have any idea of what change i have to do ?

Comment: Without changing the source for MUX show us the changes to the selects you made.  Are you switching up/down after reaching "1111"?

Comment: Notice there is no difference between the i0, i1, and i2 values in `y <= (updown and i0 and i1 and i2 and en);` and  `z <= (not updown) and i0 and i1 and i2 and en;` You've told it to ignore the updown.

Comment: yes you're right . that means that if i do z <= updown and i0 and i1 and i2 and en; 
it will be ok?

Comment: No. It's risky to comment without seeing your changes to selects. Should be `z <= not updown and not i0 and not i1 and not i2 and en;`for down. Requires tying unused inputs to used cnt inputs instead of to '1' on MUX0, MUX1 and MUX2 port maps. It's the difference between incr and decr. Show your selects changes. Add what eventually works to your question so the Q&A have value to readers.